# How to use link_to so that all parameters passed to controller are preserved in Ruby on Rails 2?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-2

I have a bilingual site with nice URLs for SEO. Using Ruby on Rails 2.3.10.

`routes.rb` fragment:

```
map.connect 'order-jira-hosting/:option.html',
    :controller => 'order', :action => 'index', :locale => 'en'
map.connect 'order-jira-with-greenhopper-hosting/:option.html',
    :controller => 'order', :action => 'index', :locale => 'en', :greenhopper => true
map.connect 'zamow-hosting-jira/:option.html',
    :controller => 'order', :action => 'index', :locale => 'pl'
map.connect 'zamow-hosting-jira-z-greenhopper/:option.html',
    :controller => 'order', :action => 'index', :locale => 'pl', :greenhopper => true
```

As you can see, `:locale` and `:greenhopper` are "hidden" in the URL.

There is a switch so that you can change the language of the current page. See my `views/layouts/default.erb`:

```
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/polish.png',  :alt => 'polski'),  { :locale => 'pl'}, :class => 'a' %>
<%= link_to image_tag('icons/english.png', :alt => 'English'), { :locale => 'en'}, :class => 'a' %>
```

I simply don't specify a controller and action so that I am redirected to the current controller and action with different locale. Unfortunately, :greenhopper parameter gets lost.

1. I am at `/order-jira-with-greenhopper-hosting/11.html`
   (`:option => 11, :locale => 'en', :greenhopper => true`)
2. Generated links for switching languages are `/order-jira-hosting/11.html` and `/zamow-hosting-jira/11.html`
   `(:option => 11, :locale => 'pl' and 'en', :greenhopper => false)`...
3. ...But they should be `/order-jira-with-greenhopper-hosting/11.html` and `/zamow-hosting-jira-z-greenhopper/11.html`
   `(:option => 11, :locale => 'pl' and 'en', :greenhopper => true)`

How to use link_to method so that all parameters passed to controller are preserved? Thanks for your help.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can base the hash you send to `link_to` off the params hash, which, if you passed it into `link_to` as-is, would reload the current page.  You can use `Hash.merge(other_hash)` to reset the `:locale` key for each link:

```
<%= link_to '<polish image />', params.merge({:locale => 'pl'}), :class => 'a' %>
```

Now, `params` *does* contain controller and action keys, but they're the controller and action that generated the current page, so the link should behave just like a page refresh, with only the parameters you changed via `params.merge` changing.

Hope this helps!

PS:  `params.merge` doesn't change the params hash, if you're concerned about that - the result of the merge is returned as a new hash.